# Prevent git apply from deleting old files

Tags: git, diff, patch

I have two files `a` and `b`, each containing their name. I create a patch like this:

```
git diff a b > test.patch
```

Now when applying the patch, file `a` is deleted:

```
git apply test.patch
```

Is there a way to prevent git from deleting the file when creating or applying the patch?

Comment: What is the output of `git status` before and after applying the patch?

Comment: @rlee827 I'm not doing this inside a repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for your usage of `git diff` is

```
git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
```

In your case, the `--no-index` is assumed implicitly. Therefore, the command

```
git diff a b
```

assumes that `b` is a newer version of the file `a`. Running your commands produces a patch that looks like this:

```
$ git diff --no-index 123.txt 456.txt
diff --git a/123.txt b/456.txt
index 97f93f4..9fa0bac 100644
--- a/123.txt
+++ b/456.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-123.txt
+456.txt
```

If you try to do this with more than 2 files, there is an error:

```
$ git diff -- 123.txt 456.txt 789.txt
Not a git repository
To compare two paths outside a working tree:
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>

$ git diff --no-index 123.txt 456.txt 789.txt
usage: git diff --no-index <path> <path>
```

One workaround (assuming you want to create a patch with both `a` and `b` added) would be to create a new git repo in a temporary directory. You can create an initial commit with no files using

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial"
```

and copy the files `a` and `b` in.

After running `git add --all`, `git diff --staged > test.patch` will create a proper patch, like this:

```
diff --git a/123.txt b/123.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..97f93f4
--- /dev/null
+++ b/123.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+123.txt
diff --git a/456.txt b/456.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..9fa0bac
--- /dev/null
+++ b/456.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+456.txt
diff --git a/789.txt b/789.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..a25ef22
--- /dev/null
+++ b/789.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+789.txt
```

Comment: This seems to be the proper answer for my specific question, though future visitors should consider using `git diff a b` to create the patch but the normal patch tool to apply it: `patch -p1 -f --dry-run < test.patch && patch -p1 -f < test.patch`